# clang disable main() prototype checking

Tags: c, clang

Is there a way to disable main() prototype checking in clang?
I mostly using unsigned int type for argc and it was perfectly fine in gcc, but clang complains (it says argc should be int) and not with just a warning but with a non-compilable error.
I know that some standards says the same, but I also know that unsigned int is okay in this case and don't want to mess with this nonsense.

Comment: *"I know that some standards says the same"* - As in **the** C standard? Just use `int` if you want to avoid any nonsense. You'll unlikely to *ever* need that extra bit worth of values.

Comment: Again, i know this, this is not the question. Yes, i don't need extra bit but also i don't need: signed arythmetic on surely unsigned values; dumb typecasting/wrapping this int to unsigned int; compiler warings about signed/unsigned comparsion when i write something like for(i=0; i<argc;i++) with, again, obviously unsigned index variable.

Comment: Well, then don't use `unsigned` types for `i` as well. Problem solved.

Comment: Right now you ask "How can I shoot myself in the foot". When told not to, you respond with "I know, but it gets in the way of me shooting myself in the other foot".

Comment: I think it is good common law to not use signed types when the program logic doesn't expect negative values. Using signed not in place is a source of many bugs.

Comment: There's no such common law. And it can in fact be a premature pessimization. Compilers are much more efficient at optimizing signed arithmetic due to the C standard imposing fewer constraints on it.

Comment: "*Is there a way to disable main() prototype checking in clang?*" [probably not](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOeKidp-iWo).

Answer (score 0):

clang uses diagnostic categories. For displaying all of them use:

```
# clang   --print-diagnostic-categories
```

Then for identifying this specific warning category use

```
# clang -fdiagnostics-show-category=id
```

It will display something as:

```
... return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type,2] ...
```

Rebuild with

```
# clang -Wno-main-return-type
```

should solve your problem.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks but the question was about argc type, not return type